# Equation for riemannian submersions from Oneill

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm revisiting Oneills paper "The fundamental equations of a submersion" and I have some trouble proofing Lemma 5. For notation, in this paper we have for a riemannian submersion $\pi: M \to B$ the two operators for vector fields $E,F$ on $M$

$T_E F := \mathscr{H}\nabla_{\mathscr{V}E}(\mathscr{V}F) + \mathscr{V}\nabla_{\mathscr{V}E}(\mathscr{H}F)
\\A_E F := \mathscr{V}\nabla_{\mathscr{H}E}(\mathscr{H}F) + \mathscr{H}\nabla_{\mathscr{H}E}(\mathscr{V}F).$

Now for these operators Lemma 5 states that
$g((\nabla_U A)_X V,W) = g(T_U V, A_X W) - g(T_U W, A_X V)$

Ok so I started computing

$g((\nabla_UA)_XV,W) = g(\nabla_U(A_XV) - A_{\nabla_UX}V - A_X(\nabla_UV),W) 
\\= g(T_UA_XV ,W)+ g(T_UV, A_XW)$

But how do I make now the final step, i.e. why is the last line equal to the right side in the Lemma?
I don't know how to show this. In my old notes it seems like I thought this step is obvious, but now that I revisit it, I don't know why.

Comment: No but it is skew-symmetric and so is $A_X$.

Comment: Yes I’m an idiot. I somehow assumed that $g(T_U A_X V,W)$ has to become $g(T_U V, A_X W) and so on. Really stupid mistake. That is why in my notes the last step is obvious. Because it actually is